# windows 8 nx (xd) enabling support for HP compaq D530

Tags: windows-8, nx, compaq-desktop-computer

I try to install win8 on HP D530 SFF... but after installation it hungs on error 0x000005d - which means no sse2, PAE or NX support - after investigation:

I found the intel spec for this processor (number SL7E2):

http://ark.intel.com/pl/products/27453/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-511-1M-Cache-2_80A-GHz-533-MHz-FSB

There's no option in  HP BIOS

Is there any possibility to turn on NX (XD BIT) - how?

Comment: the CPU itself seams to support it (http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Pentium_D/Intel-Pentium%20D%20945%20HH80553PG0964MN%20%28BX80553945%20-%20BX80553945R%29.html), but if the BIOS doesn't support it, you're SOL.

Comment: Maybe I can flash with other bios than HP Compaq? Some native?

Comment: this doesn't work. Do you use the latest BIOS?

Comment: yes, but i don't think about flashing any bios, but bios for this motherboard but not from HP

Comment: if you find the original manufacture, this maybe work, but I doubt this. Buy a new PC, your one is nearly 10 years old.

Comment: I edit question - finally i found the intel spec of my processor...